# AWS Code deploy, script failed with exit code 66

Tags: amazon-web-services, iis, aws-code-deploy

I'm using AWS Code Deploy in order to deploy my ASP.NET application into an auto-scaling group.

When deploying i've this error: `Script at specified location: application-start.bat failed with exit code 66`.

From what i've seen the **error code 66** is "`The network resource type is not correct`", which is very bizzare in this case...

My bundle contains an appspec.yml file like this:

```
version: 0.0
os: windows
files:
  - source: ./
    destination: c:\inetpub\wwwroot
hooks:
  ApplicationStop:
    - location: application-stop.bat
      timeout: 900
  ApplicationStart :
    - location: application-start.bat
      timeout: 900
```

And the bat 2 files (application-stop / application-start) only contains one line each

```
iisreset /stop

iisreset /start
```

When i go to the EC2 instance to look at the aws code deploy logs, it's not more clear to me

> 2016-04-04 08:58:42 ERROR [codedeploy-agent(2848)]: InstanceAgent::Plugins::CodeDeployPlugin::CommandPoller: Error during perform: InstanceAgent::Plugins::CodeDeployPlugin::ScriptError - Script at specified location: application-start.bat failed with exit code 66
>
> C:/Windows/TEMP/ocr512.tmp/src/lib/instance_agent/plugins/codedeploy/hook_executor.rb:150:in 'execute_script'
>
> C:/Windows/TEMP/ocr512.tmp/src/lib/instance_agent/plugins/codedeploy/hook_executor.rb:107:in 'block (2 levels) in execute'

Does anyone run into the same issues and find a way to fix it ?

Comment: Have you resolved this? It would be great to know what the fix is.

Comment: No fix at this point this keep hapening very often, but only on my preprod environment... that's very odd...
I simply reboot servers and then i can deploy again without error, but rebooting before every deployment in not really ideal.

Comment: I did a similar thing, however I used power shell scripts. Ran it over a dozen times, no errors.